# C# IOptions Pattern for Azure Functions in an Isolated Worker Process .NET 8

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-8.0, azure-functions-isolated

Has there been a change to the way the IOptions pattern is utilized in a .NET 8 Azure Functions in an Isolated Worker Process? I'm using the following code, and the dependency-injected IOptions object is always null.

*local.settings.json*

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "Example:ClientId": "coke",
    "Example:ClientSecret": "g5419c734249b7ed86"
  }
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddOptions<Example>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
        {
            configuration.GetSection("Example").Bind(settings);
        });
    })
    .Build();
```

*Options Class*

```
public class Example
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string ClientSecret { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

*DI Constructor*

```
public class MyClass(
    ILogger<MyClass> logger,
    IOptions<Example> exampleOptions)
{}
```

Comment: You should try with `"Values:Example"` in `configuration.GetSection()` since `"Example"` isn't at the top level of the configuration. I have an inkling this might be the issue.

Comment: I don't use `services.AddOptions<Example>()`
I just directly use `services.Configure` and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the use of a primary constructor. When I refactored the primary constructor:

```
public class MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger, IOptions<Example> exampleOptions){}
```

To a traditional constructor:

```
private ILogger<MyClass> logger;
private Example example;

public Acrobits(ILogger<MyClass> logger,IOptions<Example> exampleOptions)
{
    this.logger = logger;
    this.example = exampleOptions.Value;
}
```

The DI issue was resolved; however, all of the documentation I've read regarding primary constructors indicates DI of IOptions is supported.

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not -> I've started using Primary Constructors and they have been fine ... _until I tried using them with **Azure Functions**_. Suddenly -> I'm getting the exact same situation with null items passed into the main instance!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger, IOptions<Example> exampleOptions)
{
  private readonly Example example = exampleOptions.Value;
}
```

should work!